# main в war из jboss

Tags: java, java-ee

Необходимо, что бы в программе был и web и main файл, стартующий при запуске программы. Собираю для jboss с помощью мавена war и main не отрабатывает. Как и что надо настроить, что бы main отбработал. Проект сейчас по сути пустой, только main.class да jboss-web.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

main он для самостоятельных приложений.

Копать, скорее всего, в сторону аннотаций @Startup и @PostConstruct
Объявить какой-то класс инициализационным и в нем объявить методы которые будут вызыватся при создании приложения (а так же при его завершении и т.п.)
Пример:
http://www.mastertheboss.com/javaee/ejb-3/how-to-create-an-ejb-startup-service